# How to convert character vector into variable names and str_count?

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I'm trying to convert a character vector of terms into variables by a function that executes a str_count against a text dataframe, and I'm not sure how to do this.

Given a vector like:

```
variablenames <- c("strong","weak","happy","sad")
```

and a dataframe of text such as:

```
library(tidyverse)
textdf <- as.data.frame("Happy was a dwarf who was perpetually sad.") %>% rename(text = 1)
```

I *think* I want something like this:

```
countstring_fn <- function(variablenames,textdf){
for(term in variablenames){
paste0(term,"count") <- str_count(term,textdf)
}
}
```

But I'm pretty sure that doesn't work. The intended output is:

```
text,strongcount,weakcount,happycount,sadcount
"Happy was a dwarf who was perpetually sad.",0,0,1,1
```

Has anyone done something like this and made it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the `text` to lower case and check the occurrence of `variablenames` in each text and return a comma-separated string. We add word boundaries (`\\b`) to each `variablenames` to avoid matching "sad" with "saddened". We can then `separate` the data into different columns

```
library(tidyverse)

textdf %>%
   mutate(count = map_chr(tolower(text), function(x) 
    toString(map_int(paste0("\\b",variablenames,"\\b"), ~str_count(x, .x))))) %>%
  separate(count, into = paste0(variablenames, "_count"), sep = ",", convert = TRUE)

#                                        text strong_count weak_count happy_count sad_count
#1 Happy was a dwarf who was perpetually sad.            0          0           1         1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way.

```
library(tidyverse)
variablenames <- c("strong", "weak", "happy", "sad")
textdf <- tibble(
  text = c(
    '"Happy was a dwarf who was perpetually sad."',
    '"If you\'re strong, you\'re not weak."'
  )
)
textdf[, str_c(variablenames, 'count')] <- do.call(
  rbind, 
  lapply(
    textdf$text, 
    function(df) { 
      str_count(toupper(df), toupper(variablenames)) 
    }
  )
)
invisible(
  apply(
    textdf, 
    1, 
    function(vec) {
      cat(str_c(str_c(vec, collapse = ','), '\n'))
    }
  )
)
```

The main differences here is that the strings in the `textdf` dataframe come wrapped with double quotes (if you're importing data from a .csv, you can just call `str_c('"', textdf$text, '"')` for the same effect). Then, we convert all of the text and patterns to uppercase to ensure that all matches are found. Lastly, we can call `str_count()` to get a integer vector of the counts, which we can assign individually to specific columns by defining the desired column names.

The `prntFunc` function then prints each row in the data frame to console using `apply()` (vectorization is faster than using a for loop):

```
"Happy was a dwarf who was perpetually sad.",0,0,1,1
"If you're strong, you're not weak.",1,1,0,0
```

We first use `str_c()` for its collapsing ability. In other words, we can concatenate the strings in all five columns in a row into one string with `,` as the delimiter. Then, for `cat()`, we need to append a line break (`\n`) at the end of each "row string" using `str_c()` again. Finally, we can call `cat()` to display the strings in the console with special characters, such as `"`, not being accompanied by an escape character (`\`). The `cat()` call is wrapped with `invisible()` to suppress the `NULL` that `cat()` appends to the end when it is called interactively.

Answer (score 1):

```
# added second row to show output of function

textdf <- structure(list(text = c("Happy was a dwarf who was perpetually sad.",
"Sad was a dwarf who was perpetually sad.")), row.names = c(NA,
-2L), class = "data.frame")

# counting the occurrences of words in 'variablenames'

pmap_df(
  textdf, function(text) {
    map(variablenames, ~ str_count(tolower(text), pattern = .)) %>%
    t %>% as.data.frame
  }
) %>%
  setNames(variablenames) %>%
  bind_cols(textdf, .)

# Leaves you with a data frame with counts for each word as columns.

                                        text strong weak happy sad
1 Happy was a dwarf who was perpetually sad.      0    0     1   1
2   Sad was a dwarf who was perpetually sad.      0    0     0   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
library(tidyverse)

t(sapply(dat$strgs, str_count, pattern = coll(patts, T, 'en'))) %>%
  data.frame %>%
  set_names(., patts) %>%
  bind_cols(dat, .)

#   strgs                                strength ignorance present future collapse
# 1 War Is Peace, Freedom Is Slavery...  1        1         0       0      0
# 2 Who controls the past controls t...  0        0         1       1      0
# 3 The collapse of the USSR was the...  0        0         0       0      1
```

Data:

```
patts <- c("strength", "ignorance", "present", "future", "collapse")

dat <- data.frame(
  strgs = c(
    "War Is Peace, Freedom Is Slavery, and Ignorance Is Strength.",
    "Who controls the past controls the future: who controls the present controls the past.",
    "The collapse of the USSR was the greatest geopolitical catastrophe of the century."
  )
)
```